# Did i misplace brackets/semicolons?

Tags: java, android, button

Im getting an error

insert "}" to complete ClassBody for the semi colon on the 4th line. and an error on the last } on the bottom that says the same error. Any help? O and what am i supposed to put in the parenthesis --->(v==????){  Cuz apparently my button is not a variable. What should i insert for all the question marks thanks! =P

```
 public class AndroidVibrator extends Activity 
 {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        private Button sound;
        private Vibrator sound1;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
         {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main2);
            Button sound = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound);
            sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                {
                 Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) 
                           getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);    
                 public void onClick(View v)
                   {
                     if(v==????)
                      { 
                       vibrator.vibrate(300000);           
                      }
                   }
               }
          }
    }
```

Comment: Indenting correctly would help you spot any bracket errors.

Comment: you're missing a ); at the end (to close setOnClickListener)

Comment: To answer this we don't need programming knowledge. If you compare start/end of each tag, you can easily figure it out (or) As wooble said, indenting should have answered.

Comment: @user1148715 its not the newbie that annoys me, its the copy and pasting and not understanding what you're using... This defeats the purpose of being a programmer... A Copy/Paste programmer will NEVER be a true programmer.. One who seeks to understand the how, the what, and the why.

Comment: OKay! Point taken, im learning this is how i learn.I dont just jump into things i must see how they work and what they do! Now why didnt you say that instead of calling me off like that? Don't you think your comment was a little bit disrespectful?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing 2 closing curly braces `}` and  the closing `);` at the end of the call to `setOnClickListener`.

You must learn to indent code.  This is made easy in eclipse by pressing `ctrl`+`shift`+`f`

It's easiest to count if left `{`'s and right `}`'s match.

Regarding your secondary query about the button, you can remove that line (this eliminates one of your curly braces.  Checking the view identity is only useful if you are assigning the same listener to lots of views.

You can implement OnClickListener in your activity then simply call

`sound.setOnClickListener(this);`

If that were the case then you can use `if(v.getId()==R.id.sound)` to identify which view created the event but when using anonymous classes as you have here there is no need to test the view.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating anonymous ([learn how to create anonymous class](http://java.sun.com/new2java/divelog/part5/page5.jsp)) inner class to handle click action.

```
sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {   //start


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
          Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
          vibrator.vibrate(300000);
        }

     }  //end anonymous class
    );  //end setOnClickListener method.
```

Comment: No need to compare reference or id because you have single button attached to this method. Just call the vibrate() method.

Comment: getting Syntax error on token "setOnClickListener", = expected after this token for the first line u provided :/

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, use a switch case statement. It allows easier adding of more buttons.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.sound:
            vibrator.vibrate(300000);
        break;    
    }             
}
```